# Firefox using a dark theme on Vue app for no reason

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, vuetify.js

I have a Vue app that uses Vuetify. When I'm running the development server on MacOS Mojave, the page opens with a dark theme that I certainly didn't put anywhere into the styles. Besides using the dark theme, there are some components missing from the view.

If I open the app in a Firefox private window, I get the light theme and everything works as expected.

I noticed a few items in local storage that seem to be related to this:
[image]

No results show in google for the "darky" keys (`darkyMode`, `darkyState` and `darkySupported`). I'm not sure what writes and/or reads these keys and changes the theme to dark.

Other packages I'm using are leaflet and SVGjs.

Comment: Are you using a dark mode plugin for Firefox? Would explain why it doesn't affect the browser in private mode

Comment: I am using Night Eye but I disabled it. I'll try removing.

Comment: It did the trick! Silly of me thinking disabling would be enough.