# JavaScript localStorage has unexpected values

Tags: javascript, json

I'm making a very simple book listing app that is supposed to use localStorage. I have an array of Book objects (using the ES6 class) which is then saved to localStorage using JSON.stringify().

```
let array = [
    //has Book objects
];

//Book class
class Book {
    constructor(title, author, link, pages) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.link = link;
        this.pages = pages;
        this.isRead = false; 
    }
}

//saves the array whenever user adds a book listing
function addBook(book, array) {
    array.push(book);
    window.localStorage.setItem("library", JSON.stringify(array));
}
```

When I view the content of local storage, it has three additional, unexpected values such as :

```
darkyMode: "1"
darkyState: "f"
darkySupported: "t"
library: //my array of books
```

[value of localStorage][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8HRS.png

I want to remove these additional values and prevent them from appearing if possible.
Is this normal in javascript? I use bootstrap, and plain JS, if it helps.

Comment: `class Book` what's that for?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan just tried that instead of an object literal.

Comment: What is `book` in `addBook(book` ? It's not explained in your question wether the `book` is a valid Object with data.

Comment: Those keys are put there by a browser extension ([Night Eye, possibly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57529168/firefox-using-a-dark-theme-on-vue-app-for-no-reason)).

Comment: @robertklep Oh yes I have night eye. That makes sense. Alright I guess that's it

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's from my night eye extension as stated by @robertklep. Thanks guys.

Comment: Well if you want to answer your own question and provide something useful, could you consider adding what steps you took to get the solution or maybe even more information than just one sentence?

Comment: @treckstar i mean it's just it. I have Night Eye Extension in my browser that enables dark mode on any website. That causes the additional items in my localStorage